# airflow (2.1.1) LDAP instruction was wrong

Tags: docker-compose, ldap, airflow

I was following https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/security.html?highlight=ldap instruction on setting up LDAP with latest airflow image(2.1.1) with docker composer.
This section totally had no impact on login (I still only could login with default airflow/airflow),

```
[webserver]  
authenticate = True  
auth_backend = airflow.contrib.auth.backends.ldap_auth
```

Instead, I found a youtube with instructure as https://www.notion.so/Airflow-with-LDAP-in-10-mins-cbcbe5690d3648f48ee7e8ca45cb755f#e1239b1bda91489b87e4e1bc12f733a7 worked well.   Can someone help explain why airflow LDAP instruction did not work?

Answer (score 0):

One reason is that you used documentation for Airflow 1.10 for Airflow 2. This is pretty wrong and you simply used wrong documentation for different version.

But there is another `reason`: because it gives you the opportunity to improve it. If you  know instructions that works, you could submit it as PR to Airflow. It is very easy, you go to the page of Airflow documentation which you want to improve, you click "suggest improvement on this Page" and you can submit your doc improvement immediately. Airflow has more than 1700 contributors like you - it is community managed, free software. So submitting a doc improvement seems like the least you can do to pay back for the free software you use.

In short - feel free to improve Airflow documentation at any point in time.